# How can I get OS X to challenge me for password after sleep?

Tags: security, sleep-wake

I'm running version 10.6.8. Where do I go to enable password challenge after sleep?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Security and check "Require password"

- There are several selectable time delays if immediate locking isn't what you prefer.

[image]